# Integer from/to byte conversion

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk

I'm developing an app based on Samsung Chord SDK. I need to send the video's current position in the `sendDataToAll()`, which accepts data in `byte[][]`. My problem is that when I try to send the current position (which is an `int`) type-casted into `byte`, I'm getting **negative value** (in `byte`) as returned. And when I try to convert the negative value in to `int` in the `OnDataRecived()`, it's still the same negative value.
How do I solve this issue?

Sending code:

```
//for sending the message
int currPos = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
logView.append("Duration sent= " + currPos);
//Integer resume = -3;

Byte msgByte = new Byte("-3");
byte [] [] pay = new byte [1] [2];
pay[0] [0] = msgByte;

Byte msgByte2 = new Byte((byte) currPos);
logView.append("Duration sent= " + msgByte2);
pay[0] [1] = msgByte2;
mChordchannel.sendDataToAll("Integer", pay);

// im sending -3 so that im checking that the user pressed the resume .
```

Receiving code:

```
//on receiving
else if(intRec == -3) {
    Byte pos = rec[0] [1];
    int posn;
    posn = pos.intValue();
    logView.append("Duration received= " + posn);
    mVideoView.seekTo(posn);
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the type Byte to byte in these statements

```
    pay[0] [0] = msgByte;
    pay[0] [1] = msgByte2;
```

try this instead of the above

```
   pay[0] [0] = msgByte.byteValue();
   pay[0] [1] = msgByte2.byteValue();
```

This is the cause of the problem I assumed.